# firefox : why no change in my statusbar?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon

**edit**
I have a statusbar that can be used to enable and disable addons.

```
  <popupset>
  <menupopup id="inlinetransContextMenu" position="end_after">
    <image id="preficon" value="pref" />
    <menuitem id="translator-context-menuitem-preferences"
    label="preferences" onclick="alert('horay')" />
  </menupopup>
</popupset>

<!-- ========================================= -->
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a more minimal version of your code -- just enough that we can see what you're trying to do, and figure out where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define:

```
<menupopup id="inlinetransContextMenu" position="end_after">
    <image id="preficon" value="pref" />
    <menuitem id="translator-context-menuitem-preferences"
    label="preferences" onclick="alert('horay')" />
</menupopup>
```

Your popup consists of two element, an `image` and a `menuitem`. Items in a popup a laid out vertically so the image is above the menu item.

If you want to *associate* the image with the menu item, you have to do it differently, as described in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menuitem#a-image):
A `menuitem` as a property [`image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menuitem#a-image) which should hold the path to the icon. Furthermore you have to give the it the class `menuitem-iconic` for the icon to show up (it is a predefined style class (probably an XBL binding)):

> `image`
>   Type: *image URL*
>   The URL of the image to appear on the element. If this attribute is empty or left out, no image appears. The position of the image is determined by the dir and orient attributes.
>
> Note: The menuitem must have a class of menuitem-iconic for the image to appear.

So your definition should look like:

```
<menupopup id="inlinetransContextMenu" position="end_after">
    <menuitem id="translator-context-menuitem-preferences"
              image="chrome://inlinetrans/skin/pref.png"
              class="menuitem-iconic"
              label="preferences" 
              onclick="alert('horay')" />
</menupopup>
```

---

I don't understand your other problem: *why when I try to suppress the image on the statusbar is no change at all with my statusbar*. What does *suppress* mean in this context? Do you want to remove the icon? Or change?

**Update:**

You have to set `image` and `label` as attributes:

```
<statusbarpanel id="status-bar-intrans"
   context="inlinetransContextMenu"
   onclick="overlay.clickIcon(event)"
   onmouseover="var elmt=document.getElementById('status-bar-intrans');if ('enabled' == overlay.status) { elmt.tooltipText= 'inlinetrans dalam kondisi aktif';} else { elmt.tooltipText='inlinetrans dalam kondisi tidak aktif'; }">
   image="chrome://youraddon/skin/image.png"
   label="inlinetrans" />
```

and change the attribute `image`. Or via `src` and CSS. It is all described in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/statusbarpanel).

Comment: i want to change the icon,i mean when i clicked icon, addons will be inactive and when i cliked at 2nd time addons will be activate again..

Comment: @user495688: See my update. I already answered that in one of your previous questions. Nothing changed. Just try to do exactly as I wrote and read the documentation carefully. E.g. it is never written that you should create a image element inside menuitem. It should be an attribute in menuitem.

Comment: @Felix Kling : why an image and label can't appear in the browser when i change my code like yours?

Comment: @user495688: For the statusbar of for the menu?

Comment: @user495688: Well I can tell you that at this with the menuitem, it definitely works as described. So I can only assume that you are still not using it correctly... sorry. If you want to, give me a link, where I can download your extension (at least the GUI part, I don't care for the real functionality) **with** my changes as described so that I can test for myself.